# What font is used in this address?

Tags: font-identification

Can someone please tell me what font is being used in this image of an address?

[image: image of font]

Answer (score 1):

Looks more like [Univers Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/univers/pro-65-bold/) than anything else.

Also looks like it's been printed? And that the lettering is smallish, so some of the finer angles might have been filled in with ink from a less-than-precise printer.

[image: Univers screenshot]

Comment: "K" probably does not match 100%, but it has no importance I believe

Comment: @Ilan I'm guessing the lack of a perfect match is due to extra ink in the tight corners. Could be wrong though...I'd be interested to see a closer match if there is one!

Comment: maybe http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/zurich-wgl4/

Comment: @Ilan - Interesting find! Both are designed by Adrian Frutiger and look almost identical! Do you know where they differ?

Comment: @Brendan most biststream faces are licensed versions of the originals--but not with the same name. There's a weird history there but for whatever reason, bitstream licensed the faces, but not the names. Gills Sans = Humanist; Helvetica = Swiss; etc.